# Backward compatibility in HTML5 in mobile?

Tags: html, html5-video

Does HTML5 support backward compatibility in mobile?

If the browser is not support HTML5 while run a html5 page in mobile browser, whether it will throw error when audio/video is not support or we able to customize the error/alternate code. Also design wise it supports rest of tags?

Thanks in advance,

Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, unknown tags will be ignored.

I suggest you use a script such as [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect the support of the functionality you are looking to use. You can then code progressively, as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

As my opinion..
I would suggest you to use JavaScript Hack.
As old browser would simply ignore new Tags used in HTML5 and style associated with it.
Use

```
   document.createElement('HTML5tag');
```

where HTML5tag is the element/tag you want to use.
1. this will create an element and the style associated with that element will work properly.(even for old browser).
2. this should be used for every new html5 tag used by you in the head section before any style definition.